# Размещение ajax-ответа

Tags: php, ajax

Подскажите, как можно разместить разные части ответа в разных местах на странице? Запрашиваю данные с БД 2 выборки одну нужно вставить в одно место другую в другое. Не хочется делать 2 разных ajax'а, может как то можно его разделить? Вот код стандартного в принципе запроса. В ответ приходят по 3 табличных поля с разных таблиц то бишь надо вставить в 2 разных таблицы 2 части ответа.

```
     function load_form() {
        var msg = $('#client').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'load_form.php',
            data: msg,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, str) {
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
    }`
```

Comment: на стороне сервера сгенерируйте html для обоих частей. Представьте их в виде строк и запихайте в json ответ. будет у вас в ответе что-то вроде `{ content1 : "<div>part1</div>", content2 : "<div> part2</div>" }`, и каждый результат запишите куда надо `$("#results").html(data.result1)`

Comment: @teran добавь  в виде ответа прийму его

Comment: добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения html-данных для обновления нескольких частей страницы с помощью одного ajax-запроса, ответ сервера необходимо сформировать в формате `json`. Поля сформированного ответа будут содержать html-код для обновления отдельных частей страницы. Это может выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
    //в случае применения шаблонизаторов типа Smarty
    $result['content1'] = $smarty->fetch('content1.tpl');
    //в случае ручной генерации html
    $result['content2'] = "<div>content2</div>";

    echo json_encode($result);
```

при получении ответа ajax-запроса следует обновить нужные части страницы, используя контент соответствующих полей ответа.

```
        success: function (result) {
            var data = JSON.parse(result); 
            $('#results-1').html(data.content1);
            $("#results-2").html(data.content2);
        },
```

Comment: Странно все запросы работают а когда пробую такое: `$json['chkveg'] .= "<option value= ". $phone['phone'] ." >".
                        $phone['comments'] ." => ". $phone['phone'] ." </option>";` отправить обратно на странице непашет (выдает ошибку хотя в респонсе код есть правда значения остаются в джейсоне обратно их неперекодирует им чего то экранирует слеши хотя другие запросы неэкранирует).

Comment: @ASYOU не совсем понял проблему, но возможно вам поможет изучения второго параметра функции [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: в певом случае все ок как я и написал когда пробую получить выше написанный ответ получаю вместо него `{"chkveg":"<option value= ****** >\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0440\u0430 => ***** <\/option>` то бишь текст внутри обратно не декодится (велью все ок цифры есть) хотя в предыдущем скрипте все ок+ экранирует слеши в опшине и в конце ничего не выводит возвращая ошибку.

Comment: @ASYOU попробуйте с флагом `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`